# Sending request on deactivation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a theoretical question, let's say I have a standard react form that sends update request to my API whenever I submit it by clicking on my submit button BUT I would like to send the request only when I clickOff / deactivate the input without the need for the button (does that make sense?).

I tried react-offclick package but the problem is that It sends the request whenever I click anywhere else on the page.

Sending the request on value change will not work in this case, is this possible? how do I approach this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is an onBlur that you can use on the input element that will fire with it loses focus. https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You don't need a library, inputs have the [onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) event (the opposite of onfocus). Just trigger your submit function when input loses focus